# Order of movement in a maze based on user input

Tags: python, if-statement, controls, operator-precedence

I am trying to solve a `maze` using stack where each move is stored in the `moves` variable. In order to solve it I need to arbitrarily decide the order to check the availability of four directions from the current position. One of possible ordering is 1) up, 2) down, 3) left and 4) right. For a different movement pattern, the if-statements should be swapped accordingly.

Is there a more elegant way to do this, with the possibility of defining the `order_of_movement` variable and ***not*** swapping if-statements?

```
order_of_movement = ['UP', 'DOWN', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT'] #how such a movement list could be used?

if(not moved and validWay[UP]):
    moved, completed, moves = move_up(moves, maze, end)

if(not moved and validWay[DOWN]):
    moved, completed, moves = move_down(moves, maze, end)

if(not moved and validWay[LEFT]):
    moved, completed, moves = move_left(moves, maze, end)

if(not moved and validWay[RIGHT]):
    moved, completed, moves = move_right(moves, maze, end)
```

Comment: Do your `move_up/down/left/right` functions need to be separate? If a direction were passed as a parameter to a more generic `move_direction` function, then you could just do a simple `for` loop over `order_of_movement`. If they have to be separate then you could have a dictionary that maps each direction to each function, but without knowing the implementation of your `move_` functions I can't really help more than that.

Comment: At the moment the move functions are separate. The functions are used to move from one grid cell to another depending on whether there is a path. Having a generic move function should solve the problem. I could not understand how to implement the dictionary in the second solution?

Comment: I added an answer which clarifies the second solution and demonstrates how your code could look with the first solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you clarified that your `move_up/down/left/right` function could be made generic, here's how the solution could look:

```
for direction in order_of_movement:
    if(not moved and validWay[direction]):
        moved, completed, moves = move_direction(moves, maze, end, direction)
```

This is assuming you added a fourth argument, `direction`, to your new generic `move_direction` function.

What I meant in my comment about a dictionary was that if you wanted to keep all your move functions separate, you could define a mapping of directions to functions, like this:

```
order_of_movement = {
    'UP': move_up,
    'DOWN': move_down,
    'LEFT': move_left,
    'RIGHT': move_right
}

for direction in order_of_movement.keys():
    if(not moved and validWay[direction]):
        moved, completed, moves = order_of_movement[direction](moves, maze, end)
```

Because each direction is mapped to a function, that means that `order_of_movement[direction]` gives you the appropriate function, so you just have to call it by adding the arguments in parentheses to the end.